# Removing HTML tags from Magento posts to Facebook

Tags: facebook, magento, magento-1.7

When I post links to Magento product pages on Facebook, sometimes I get HTML tags in the Facebook snippets.

I've added meta descriptions to both the products you see here.

[image: Image of 2 Facebook posts, one with HTML showing and another with the meta description.]

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Reread your question!

It looks like some of your products have html tags in the meta_description, so worth having a look at that, but that's not the main issue.

Now I've fully understood the issue, take a look at this great tutorial to solve your problem by setting the correct meta data for Facebook http://www.gofishclientcatchers.com/internet-marketing-blog/development-blog/facebook-meta-tags-for-magento/

The important part which relates to your issue is the strip_tags php function;

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(Mage::registry('current_product')->getShortDescription()); ?>" />
```

You could also use;

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription()); ?>" />
```

If you are not creating a short description.

T

Comment: Actually, this HTML tag issue seems to happen more often when we don't use the WYSIWYG. And it's not just iframes: some posts show the top few HTML tags, whatever they are.

Comment: plan A then!  in admin go to catalog > attributes > manage attributes. find the attribute you are using, open it, and make sure it has 'allow HTML tags on front end' enabled.

Comment: sorry im re-reading your original question - I realise now you are saying that Facebook is displaying the tags?  You also say you're adding this data in the meta description? You should never add html tags to meta descriptions

Comment: No, @PixieMedia, not using HTML in meta description. That's just plain text. In some cases, Facebook is using the meta descriptions for snippets under photos, but in others, it's showing the HTML tags from the product description (even though there is a meta description available).

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but you are getting code in there - on your product 'Mosa Mack: Science Detective' (found your site) look at the meta description, its: <meta content="<p>Join the young, hip, and savvy Mosa Mack and her rag tag crew as they get to the bottom of gripping (and funny) science cases.<p>" name="description">

Im guessing you're copying and pasting it from somewhere and inadvertently including tags

Comment: infact in the code its; content="&lt;p&gt;Join the young.  &lt; renders as "<".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! In any case, that's not the post in the photo I shared. I just double-checked that one: no tags there, just plain text. On the site, the meta description is just a string.

Comment: To be totally clear: it's not showing tags with the meta description, it's pulling tags from the product description instead.

Comment: fully understand the issue now, have updated the answer which should help you.